# Jquery Ajax GET method implemantation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i have one aspx page which is implemented with JQuery and with Ajax post method. I am new in JQuery, So i wish to study the jquery. I found one jquery method in which they are calling the $.Ajax () method with GET. The code is shown below.

```
function AddSection(){
        name = $("#ddlSections").attr("value");
        sectionID = "p"+ sectionsCount++;

        var response = $.ajax(
            {
                type: "GET",
                async:false,
                url: '/s/documents/sectioninit.aspx?id='+sectionID+'&name='+name

            });

        $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1__editors').append(response.responseText);}
```

When I checked the sectioninit.aspx without any querystring values it returns like this:

```
<div id="">
<input type="hidden" name="hSectionName" value=""/>
<h3>
    <a href="#" onclick="refreshSection('')">
        </a></h3>
        <input id="btnUp" type="button" value="Up" onclick="moveDiv('', 'up')" />
        <input id="btnDown" type="button" value="Down" onclick="moveDiv('', 'down')" />
        <input id="btnRemove" type="button" value="Delete" onclick="removeDiv('')" />
<input id="h" type="hidden" value="false"/>

    <div name="c">
        <textarea id="editorInstance" name="editorInstance" rows="80" cols="80"><ul><li>first item</li><li>second item</li><li>third item</li></ul></textarea>
    </div>
```

But when I pass the the query string values, It returns awesome code that I want.

```
<div id="p5">
<input type="hidden" name="hSectionNamep5" value="Free"/>
<h3>
    <a href="#" onclick="refreshSection('p5')">
        Free</a></h3>
        <input id="btnUpp5" type="button" value="Up" onclick="moveDiv('p5', 'up')" />
        <input id="btnDownp5" type="button" value="Down" onclick="moveDiv('p5', 'down')" />
        <input id="btnRemove" type="button" value="Delete" onclick="removeDiv('p5')" />
<input id="hp5" type="hidden" value="false"/>

    <div name="cp5">
        <textarea id="editorInstancep5" name="editorInstancep5" rows="80" cols="80"><ul><li>first item</li><li>second item</li><li>third item</li></ul></textarea>
    </div>
```

Can anybody help me for getting the above result while i passing the query string values. It would be rather helpful for me for resolving my project risk area. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check in Page_Load event like that

```
 if (!IsPostBack){
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["name"]) )
        {
           Request.QueryString["id"]) = string.Empty;
           Request.QueryString["name"]= string.Empty;
           //or write your logic here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code

** Ajax Code **

```
function AddSection(){
    name = $("#ddlSections").attr("value");
    sectionID = "p"+ sectionsCount++;
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:'/s/documents/sectioninit.aspx?id='+sectionID+'&name='+name,
            async:true,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (responseText) {
                $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1__editors').append(responseText);}
            },
            error: function (result) {

            }
        });
```